# How to properly clean a mouthguard (e.g., a nightguard)?

Tags: dentistry, mouth-guard

How to properly clean a [mouthguard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mouthguard)
 (e.g., a nightguard)?

For example, https://mouthguardsforteethgrinding.com/how-to-clean-your-mouth-guard-effectively/ ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20180118222436/https://mouthguardsforteethgrinding.com/how-to-clean-your-mouth-guard-effectively/)) mentions 7 general methods:

- Toothbrush and toothpaste
- Mouth Rinse
- Soap and Water
- Mouth guard cleaning tablets
- Dental sanitizing devices
- Natural cleaning methods

Are the equally efficient?

For example, I have read on https://riverrundentalspa.com/instructions-for-cleaning-your-night-guard/ ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20180118222645/https://riverrundentalspa.com/instructions-for-cleaning-your-night-guard/)) that the use of toothpaste is deleterious to the mouthguard:

> You don’t need to apply toothpaste to the brush. Since toothpaste can be abrasive, it may scratch your night guard and cause it to wear out more quickly.

Answer (score -1):

Make a habit of deep cleansing your night guard as least once weekly. This may be done several ways. The first is by using an over-the-counter pipes cleaner. Simply put your night guard in a bowl or glass with water and allow the cleaner to dissolve entirely into the water.

The second way to deep clean your night guard is by using a mixture of vinegar and hydrogen peroxide. Soak the night guard in white vinegar for a minimum of 30 minutes. After soaking, rinse the night guard and the bowl with water. Then soak the night guard in hydrogen peroxide for at least 30 more minutes. Once completed, rinse with water and permit the nighttime guard to dry completely.

The last way that you can deep clean your night guard would be to use a combination of mouthwash and water. Pour a capful of toothpaste right to a bowl or glass and then dilute with water until the night guard is submerged in the solution. Let your night guard soak for approximately 30 minutes and then rinse the nighttime guard and permit it to dry completely on a clean flat surface.

Pro Suggestion: Do not ever leave your nighttime protector soaking in anything for more than one hour. Lengthy time in liquid may harm the material your nighttime guard is made out of.

Comment: Welcome to Health.SE. Since health is an important topic, the site has a strict policy that all answers should be [backed up with reliable references](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/should-we-require-references-to-back-up-all-answers) so that the answer can be independently verified, regardless of the reader's background. *See [this list of reliable sources](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/783/quality-of-references/784#784)*. If you still have trouble with this, feel free to visit the [help] or [meta].

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your answers! I would encourage you to read the help section and take the tour as Carey has suggested. Also, any affiliations you have need to be disclosed. I have edited out your links as they were flagged as being possible spam. You are free to use links in your profile, however. See [this section](https://health.stackexchange.com/help/behavior) to learn more.